# Unable to start steam on lubuntu

Tags: steam

Whenever I try to start steam I am greeted with this error message:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1428965940)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with my graphics card.

Comment: run: `sudo apt-get update` and then run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri`

Comment: also, see here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193802 although, I would suggest backing up those files before removing them just in case

Comment: Thanks the linked helped a lot :) its working pefectly now , is there a way to give u some sorta thumbs up ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Error in installing Steam on ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635851/error-in-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04/648953#648953) post.

This problem don't seem to affect the closed source drivers, only the open ones.