# Steam doesn't start. LibGL error

Tags: steam

Steam doesn't launch... trying to run it from the icon doesn't do anything, no errors, nothing.

Trying to launch from the terminal and I get this:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 61):

To fix it simply open the terminal and run these commands:

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Steam should then work properly. But make sure not to install the proprietary AMD drivers as they are very bad for the stability of the OS compared to the open source drivers. If you are getting low performance with the open source drivers, then simply upgrade the Mesa version by adding the xorg-edgers PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

After that type this in order to upgrade the Mesa version:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then reboot and the new Mesa driver should be loaded.

Comment: this seemed to work for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks

Comment: The file `~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1` doesn't exist?

Comment: @jvriesem that's not a problem, as you'd have to remove it anyway. The point of this exercise is to make Steam use the system versions of certain core libraries instead of replacing them with versions that don't work. (Why they would ship incompatible versions of standard libraries in the first place is beyond me)

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.10 this trick doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed my problem running Steam on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, though the second command wasn't necessary as the file didn't exist in the first place.

Comment: FYI comment #6 at https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/installing-recommended-mesa-driver-problem/11436 lists alternatives to xorg-edgers ppa.

Comment: Worked for me on 17.10 (just the first two lines)

Comment: Confirmed that this fix works for Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 18.04. I removed all the libraries in the folder though.

Answer (score 22):

This got me most of the way there. I also needed to change the way I launched Steam.

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

As per this thread: [Error in installing Steam on ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635851/error-in-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04/648953#648953)

Comment: This is the only thing that finally fixed my issue. Why?

Comment: @Calabacin its launching Steam, but not with the libraries Steam defines. LD_PRELOAD can "inject" new or different libraries. Normally these would be loaded with drivers/etc, but in the case of Raedon OSD and friends, they may not, or not the most powerful/right ones. Its a hotfix. You can edit the Steam shortcut or menu items with this launcher too, which is what I believe he is saying by "change the way I launch Steam".

Comment: Actually, I just saved the line above in an sh file and execute that through the terminal. Modifying the shortcut could work too.

As for why this fixed the issue, I wish I had more information. I'm just glad my post was helpful.