# Steam wont launch on Ubuntu 15.04 64Bit

Tags: command-line, 15.04, 64-bit, steam

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, so I don't know if this is a simple fix or not. I've read some fixes to answers for my problem but I don't really know how to do any of the things they're telling me to do (such as installing proprietary drivers). I'm having the same problem that UbhiSukhpal posted about, but my attempts at fixing the problem have not been successful. Starting Steam from Terminal hasn't worked either. This is the message I get when I try to do start it from the terminal.

```
    chris@chris-VPCEE41FX:~$ steam
    Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
    STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
    libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
    libGL error: driver pointer missing
    libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
    libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
    libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Any help would be awesome. I apologize if this is going to be tedious. :p

Comment: 15.04 is out of date ind is not supported.

Comment: Do you have an AMD graphic chip in this box? I think that is what the r600 refers to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04 (or http://askubuntu.com/questions/654566/steam-doesnt-start-libgl-error )

Comment: Mordoc, yes I do. I updated Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Arch Linux but not on Ubuntu. On Arch I solved it by using this script to launch Steam.

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libgpg-error.so' steam
```

You can adapt and integrate that into `/usr/share/applications/steam.desktop` or make a new launch script, like `/usr/bin/steam-start`

You can also solve it by removing certain libraries from the steam-runtime folder. I used that before but the steam-runtime tends to get regenerated so I don't recommend this. I don't remember the exact files but here's a [useful discussion](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193802).

On Arch this is caused by the system libraries being at the latest version, and thus incompatible with Steam. On Ubuntu this shouldn't be an issue since they are at a supported version, and Ubuntu is a supported distro by Valve.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have worked by running it through Terminal. Do I need to run that script every time I want to launch Steam?

Comment: Not necessarily. Just create a script in /usr/bin/steam-start (or other name that you feel confortable with) with the that command (don't forget to make it executable) and then edit /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop Exec line to match your script's path