# Steam won't start (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, games, steam

I tried booting with any method possible: via Menu, via Terminal, not gonna work. The content of the "error.log" is:

```
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1581460722)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1581460722)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1581460722)
Gtk-Message: 17:19:46.053: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 17:19:46.053: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  48
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  47
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  49
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
assert_20200303171944_1.dmp[13018]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20200303171944_1.dmp
/home/schminuxoid/.steam/steam.sh: строка 722: 12985 Ошибка сегментирования                   (стек памяти сброшен на диск) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
assert_20200303171944_1.dmp[13018]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20200303171944_1.dmp[13018]: response: CrashID=bp-138d4235-d3a1-43dd-8ba6-ee5bb2200303
assert_20200303171944_1.dmp[13018]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20200303171944_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-138d4235-d3a1-43dd-8ba6-ee5bb2200303''
```

(Im Russian, thats right)
What should I do?

Comment: something helpful? https://askubuntu.com/questions/654566/steam-doesnt-start-libgl-error

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall it:

```
sudo apt purge steam-launcher
sudo rm -fr ~/.local/share/Steam && rm -fr ~/.steam
```

And install it again:

- Open a terminal
- Download a package: `wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb`
- Install it: `sudo apt install steam.deb`
  It asks about Starting steam to configure it for current user. I click the button and input my user's password when it prompts.

  Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start packages downloading and installing.
  At the end it asks to `Press return to continue:`. I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it closes terminal window. After this Steam window with **Updating Steam...** progress bar appears a few times.