# Can not launch Steam on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, steam

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 few days back, and I installed possibly the most important software for it. But, I never works for some reason. I tried to reinstall Steam even that didn't work, now I try to launch steam from the Terminal I get this error message. [image] thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in installing Steam on ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635851/error-in-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Driver issue open up Additional Drivers with this command:

```
/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4
```

Install the one of the `proprietary Drivers` if that dose not work.

Install the `Open Source Driver` if that dose not work.

Install the `recommended driver`