# Steam on Ubuntu 16.04 and AMD driver

Tags: steam

I have a problem launching steam in ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Tried installing with the sudo command apt-get install steam it works I agree on the privacy note.

But when I try to open steam it flashes and then disappears from taskbar.

Comment: Which graphics are you using (you can use `lshw -C display` or `lspci -v`). The issue may be more related to steam etc not supporting more recent Linux systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 does not have AMD support yet.

see link below

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

I have the same issue.... waiting for amd drivers to install ubuntu 16.04

[update]

however surfing on the web, i found this link about amdgpu-pro drivers

http://www.pcworld.com/article/3075837/linux/amds-gaming-optimized-amdgpu-pro-driver-for-linux-is-in-beta.html

Comment: There is AMD support... just no stable proprietary drivers :)

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:
Start Steam with

```
#!/bin/bash

export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' #Export so all child processes are affected as well

export DISPLAY=:0

#export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose

steam
```

Source: [Error in installing Steam on ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635851/error-in-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: works on 16.04 with amd drm driver.. steam is started,and updating now. confirmed!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:

https://wirejungle.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/how-to-fix-broken-steam-linux-client-with-radeon-graphics-driver-workaround/

just follow the guide, steam works around step 4

Answer (score 0):

```
cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

It worked for me... but please note that if some game required that old lib from the steam runtime, it may crash (that is why should be valve fixing this)