# How to install steam on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: package-management, steam

My laptop is on Ubuntu 16.04 ,64bit.What I have learnt from here

[Error in installing Steam on ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635851/error-in-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04/648953#648953)

```
DISPLAY=:0 glxinfo | grep -i direct
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_direct_state_access,


steam
No command 'steam' found, did you mean:
```

I my .steam directory I have this

```
bin               controller_base  linux32       resource  starting                     steam.pipe                   ubuntu12_32
bin32             error.log        linux64       root      steam                        steam.sh                     ubuntu12_64
bin64             fontconfig       package       sdk32     steamdeps.txt                tenfoot
bin_steamdeps.py  friends          public        sdk64     steam_install_agreement.txt  ThirdPartyLegalNotices.css
bin_steam.sh      graphics         registry.vdf  servers   steam_msg.sh                 ThirdPartyLegalNotices.doc
config            html5app         remoteui      skins     steam.pid                    ThirdPartyLegalNotices.html
```

Which package do I need,32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Hi, did you found solution? I'm trying to install steam too