# Steam - Unable/failed to load multiple drivers

Tags: drivers, steam

I was trying to run steam from the launcher but it never opened. I ran `steam` in the terminal and this was the output:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1504757234)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I haven't the first idea of how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.04+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04) or [Error in installing Steam on ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635851/error-in-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04) We have a number of these. The answers are mostly not limited to old releases like 15.04; I believe you should be able to get a solution. See also the linked questions (listed on the right side of each page) on those two questions. You can **[edit]** to update this if they don't enable you to fix it.

Comment: I was booting Ubuntu Budgie installed on an external hard drive on my father's computer and he uses a lot of adapters for stuff and he said that that was what the issue was. As such, I don't need to install the drivers; i never use his computer, I was just curious how well it would run.