# How to install Steam on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (I've never used linux before)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, steam

I just set up my old computer with some new parts today and got it up and running. no old windows key so I used a friends USB drive to put Ubuntu on here hoping to just be able to use my computer until I find the money to get windows and I'm running into the issue of download steam. Originally I downloaded it through steampowered.com like any old person would...then when that didnt work my friend refrenced me some commands in the terminal and when those didnt work i watched a video about installing steam installer through Ubuntu Software and thats where I'm at...

my set up consists of...

```
GPU: GTX 960 4GB ?(Gallium 0.4 on NV126)?
CPU: Ryzen 3 1200
RAM: 8GB 2133mhz
MOBO: MSI Tomahawk B350
64 bit OS
```

When launching steam through the terminal this is the process it goes through.

```
:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: Have you checked the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635851/error-in-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal by Pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and the copy paste the following commands :

First Run the following command to uninstall steam :

```
sudo apt-get purge steam-launcher && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then install Steam by Using the following command :

```
sudo apt install steam
```

Then Launch Steam and it should work fine.