# libGL nouveau driver missing error

Tags: drivers, opengl

So, I recently got a ticket from a client complaining that our software was crashing on his ubuntu 16.04 PC. He stated that the software was working originally but when he tried using it some time later, the software crashes.

His original run gave the following errors / warnings:

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so 
libGL error: driver pointer missing 
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau 
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so 
libGL error: driver pointer missing 
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau 
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so 
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pushButton_browse_released() 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_checkBox_localRunMode_toggled(bool) 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_checkBox_remoteRunMode_toggled(bool) 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pushButton_browse_released() 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_checkBox_localRunMode_toggled(bool) 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_checkBox_remoteRunMode_toggled(bool) 
QObject::connect: No such slot S3DGui::slotOnCentralTabChanged(int) 
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area 
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area 
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area 
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area 
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed 
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed 
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed 
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed 
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed 
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed 
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed 
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed 
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed 
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed 
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I followed the answer @ [Error in installing Steam on ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635851/error-in-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04/648953#648953) 
to localize the issue, but it failed.

I had asked him to send me an output of LIBGL_DEBUG, the output for that was:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose ./<Project_script name>
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/<name>/.drirc: No such file or directory. 
libGL: pci id for fd 9: 10de:1bb0, driver nouveau 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/nouveau_dri.so 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so 
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_amdgpu.so.1: undefined symbol: drmSyncobjWait) 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/nouveau_dri.so 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/nouveau_dri.so 
libGL: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/nouveau_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/nouveau_dri.so 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/nouveau_dri.so 
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/nouveau_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) 
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so 
libGL error: driver pointer missing 
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau 
libGL: pci id for fd 9: 10de:1bb0, driver nouveau 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/nouveau_dri.so 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so 
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_amdgpu.so.1: undefined symbol: drmSyncobjWait) 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/nouveau_dri.so 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/nouveau_dri.so 
libGL: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/nouveau_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/nouveau_dri.so 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/nouveau_dri.so 
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/nouveau_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) 
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so 
libGL error: driver pointer missing 
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so 
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_amdgpu.so.1: undefined symbol: drmSyncobjWait) 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so 
libGL: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so 
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) 
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so 
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast 
function is no-op 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pushButton_browse_released() 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_checkBox_localRunMode_toggled(bool) 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_checkBox_remoteRunMode_toggled(bool) 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pushButton_browse_released() 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_checkBox_localRunMode_toggled(bool) 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_checkBox_remoteRunMode_toggled(bool) 
QObject::connect: No such slot S3DGui::slotOnCentralTabChanged(int) 
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area 
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area 
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area 
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area 
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area 
function is no-op 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
function is no-op 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
function is no-op 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
function is no-op 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
function is no-op 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
function is no-op 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
function is no-op 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
function is no-op 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
function is no-op 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
Unrecognized OpenGL version 
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
function is no-op 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As you can see the project uses Qt and OpenGL. I don't really have any idea of what the issue might be. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

P.S I noticed that his libraries as in lib/ folder (though he is using x86_64 libs) while ours is in lib64/ (where the code works just fine).

Comment: I'm not sure if Ubuntu can run without this package, but can you check that `libgl1-mesa-dri` is still installed?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll ask my client to check for the package. Would love some other suggestions as well thanks.